# Creating ATL COM server in windows 8 metro style mode

Tags: windows-8

I have a requirement to create an ATL COM service which does some operation in background always. I want to know, can we create a service in Windows-8 Metro style mode ?
if so, how to create the service ? if not, what is the alternative solution for this ?
Please share your taught on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't have a always-on service running in the background in Metro-style apps. The WinRT framework discourages the use of apps that are always running - to conserve battery and provide a good user-experience for the user. Only one (or two if you include snapped-mode) app can be active - the one in the foreground - all other apps which are in the background are suspended and don't get any CPU time.

You can, however, use [BackgroundTasks](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9) to do something periodically or when a system event occurs.